# Adding a clickable link to a background image slider

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I apologize in advance if this question has been answered already.

I'm a newb when it comes to php and css (can get along with html ok).  I've been banging my head against the wall trying to get this to work with no luck so far after spending a fair amount of time on Google and various forums.

My goal is to make the background images on the slider of the homepage (http://etractorimplements.com/) clickable links.

Here is the code:

```
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<!-- Item 1 -->
<?php               
$args = array('posts_per_page' => '-1','category' =>22, 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'post_type' => 'post');                
$recent = get_posts($args);             
$count = 0;                 
$i=1;               
foreach( $recent as $post ){                
$image_url= wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );          ?>
<div class="item lazy slide<?php echo $i;?> <?php echo ($count == 0) ? 'active' : ''; ?>" role="list">
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-7 text-left my_res1">
<h3 data-animation="animated fadeIn"> <?php echo $post->post_title;?></h3>
<h4 data-animation="animated fadeInUp"> <?php echo $post->post_content;?></h4> </div>
<div class="col-md-5 text-right my_res2">
<!--<img  data-animation="animated bounceInUp" src="img/a.png"> --></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<style>
#first-slider .slide<?php echo $i;
?> {
background-image: url(<?php echo $image_url;?>);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
}
</style>\
```

I want each of the four sliders to link to the corresponding category page (i.e. slide: 1 - Ditch Flail Mower links to "Flail Mowers" category page)

When I inspect the page source I can see the corresponding html code:

```
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<!-- Item 1 -->
<div class="item lazy slide1 active" role="list">
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-7 text-left my_res1">
<h3 data-animation="animated fadeIn"> Ditch Flail Mower</h3>
<h4 data-animation="animated fadeInUp"> Ideal for your small to mid-sized tractor
providing maximum flexibility</h4> </div>
<div class="col-md-5 text-right my_res2">
<!--<img  data-animation="animated bounceInUp" src="img/a.png"> --></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<style>
#first-slider .slide1 {
background-image: url(https://etractorimplements.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/flailmower.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
}
</style>
<div class="item lazy slide2 " role="list">
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-7 text-left my_res1">
<h3 data-animation="animated fadeIn"> Wood Chipper</h3>
<h4 data-animation="animated fadeInUp"> Powerful &amp; Reliable
Easy to Use</h4> </div>
<div class="col-md-5 text-right my_res2">
<!--<img  data-animation="animated bounceInUp" src="img/a.png"> --></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<style>
#first-slider .slide2 {
background-image: url(https://etractorimplements.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/sl2-compressor.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
}
</style>
<div class="item lazy slide3 " role="list">
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-7 text-left my_res1">
<h3 data-animation="animated fadeIn"> Rotary Tiller</h3>
<h4 data-animation="animated fadeInUp"> To make your work easy,
the right size to fit your tractor.</h4> </div>
<div class="col-md-5 text-right my_res2">
<!--<img  data-animation="animated bounceInUp" src="img/a.png"> --></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<style>
#first-slider .slide3 {
background-image: url(https://etractorimplements.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/sl4-compressor.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
}
</style>
<div class="item lazy slide4 " role="list">
<div class="row">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-7 text-left my_res1">
<h3 data-animation="animated fadeIn"> Snow Plow</h3>
<h4 data-animation="animated fadeInUp"> Innovative &amp; reliable plow that removes
snow even in the worst conditions</h4> </div>
<div class="col-md-5 text-right my_res2">
<!--<img  data-animation="animated bounceInUp" src="img/a.png"> --></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<style>
#first-slider .slide4 {
background-image: url(https://etractorimplements.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/snow-banner.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
}
</style>
</div>
<!-- End Wrapper for slides-->
```

- slide1 should link to https://etractorimplements.com/product-category/flail-mowers/
- slide2 should link to https://etractorimplements.com/product-category/wood-chippers/
- slide3 should link to https://etractorimplements.com/product-category/rotary-tillers/
- slide4 should link to https://etractorimplements.com/product-category/winter-equipments/snowplow/

Can anybody help me figure out the correct code to insert into the "frontpage.php" file?

Thanks in advance!

rabiancone

Comment: Please click edit. then `[<>]` snippet editor and post a [mcve] of JUST relevant HTML, CSS and script. No need for PHP

Comment: There are no hrefs or script to redirect in your code

Comment: If you want our help, you need to provide a [mcve]. Your site is minified so no useful HTML or script to be found

Comment: @mplungjan First off I want to say thanks for helping me out with this.  As far as I know, the plugin I use to minify is WP Rocket.  I tried to eliminate the minification by unchecking the boxes in the plugin setting but nothing changed in the code from what I could tell.  It appears that I only have access to .php and .css files but not .html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code wrapped in `<script></script>`into (the head of) your page

```
const links = {
  slide1: "https://etractorimplements.com/product-category/flail-mowers/",
  slide2: "https://etractorimplements.com/product-category/wood-chippers/",
  slide3: "https://etractorimplements.com/product-category/rotary-tillers/",
  slide4: "https://etractorimplements.com/product-category/winter-equipments/snowplow/"
}; // list of links

$(function() {
  $(".carousel-inner").css("cursor","pointer"); // or add .carousel-inner { cursor: pointer; } to the end of your CSS file
  $(".carousel-inner").on("click tap touchstart", ".item", function() {
    const slide = $(this).attr("class").split(/\s+/).filter(cls => cls.startsWith("slide"))
    if (slide.length === 1) location = links[slide[0]];
  });
});
```

Example

```js
const links = {
  slide1: "https://etractorimplements.com/product-category/flail-mowers/",
  slide2: "https://etractorimplements.com/product-category/wood-chippers/",
  slide3: "https://etractorimplements.com/product-category/rotary-tillers/",
  slide4: "https://etractorimplements.com/product-category/winter-equipments/snowplow/"
}

$(function() {
  $(".carousel-inner").css("cursor","pointer");
  $(".carousel-inner").on("click tap touchstart", ".item", function() {
    const slide = $(this).attr("class").split(/\s+/).filter(cls => cls.startsWith("slide"))
    if (slide.length === 1) location = links[slide[0]];
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="first-slider">
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item slide1" role="list">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-7 text-left my_res1">
              <h3 data-animation="animated fadeIn"> Ditch Flail Mower</h3>
              <h4 data-animation="animated fadeInUp"> Ideal for your small to mid-sized tractor providing maximum flexibility</h4>
            </div>
            <a href="https://etractorimplements.com/product-category/flail-mowers/"></a>
            <div class="col-md-5 text-right my_res2"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <style>
        #first-slider .slide1 {
          background-image: url(https://etractorimplements.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/flailmower.jpg);
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: contain;
          background-position: center
        }
      </style>
      <div class="item slide2 active" role="list">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-7 text-left my_res1">
              <h3 data-animation="animated fadeIn"> Wood Chipper</h3>
              <h4 data-animation="animated fadeInUp"> Powerful &amp; Reliable Easy to Use</h4>
            </div>
            <a href="https://etractorimplements.com/product-category/flail-mowers/"></a>
            <div class="col-md-5 text-right my_res2"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <style>
        #first-slider .slide2 {
          background-image: url(https://etractorimplements.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/sl2-compressor.jpg);
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: contain;
          background-position: center
        }
      </style>
      <div class="item slide3" role="list">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-7 text-left my_res1">
              <h3 data-animation="animated fadeIn"> Rotary Tiller</h3>
              <h4 data-animation="animated fadeInUp"> To make your work easy, the right size to fit your tractor.</h4>
            </div>
            <a href="https://etractorimplements.com/product-category/flail-mowers/"></a>
            <div class="col-md-5 text-right my_res2"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <style>
        #first-slider .slide3 {
          background-image: url(https://etractorimplements.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/sl4-compressor.jpg);
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: contain;
          background-position: center
        }
      </style>
      <div class="item slide4" role="list">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-7 text-left my_res1">
              <h3 data-animation="animated fadeIn"> Snow Plow</h3>
              <h4 data-animation="animated fadeInUp"> Innovative &amp; reliable plow that removes snow even in the worst conditions</h4>
            </div>
            <a href="https://etractorimplements.com/product-category/flail-mowers/"></a>
            <div class="col-md-5 text-right my_res2"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <style>
        #first-slider .slide4 {
          background-image: url(https://etractorimplements.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/snow-banner.jpg);
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: contain;
          background-position: center
        }
      </style>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev"> <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i><span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next"> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i><span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The file that controls the homepage is "frontpage.php" which does not contain a <head> tag.  I pasted the above code snippet into the beginning of the file but only a long string of text appeared on the homepage.   

The "header.php" contains a <head> tag.  I copied the provided code into the <head> tag on "header.php" and got the same result.

I apologize that I'm doing a poor job of explaining what's happening and unable to provide you with the necessary info to help me.

Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: The code needs to be wrapped in a <script></script> tag

Comment: Thank you, sir.  That did the trick.  Of course, now I have more questions, lol.  I assumed when the images became clickable links the cursor would turn into a pointer finger upon hover indicating that it is a link however it remains an arrow.  If possible, I would like to pointer finger to display upon hover.  Also, the links do not appear to work on mobile (tested on safari and chrome app), only desktop.  Do you know if there's a way to remedy this or could it be the nature of the code? Either way I am eternally grateful for your help.

Comment: Or add to your CSS: `.carousel-inner { cursor: pointer; }`.

Comment: @kmoser If he can find one that is not generated by the plugin

Comment: @mplungjan What do you mean? He just needs to add that one line to his existing style sheet.

Comment: Sure. But that is very random. In this case adding it with the jQuery that makes it clickable makes more sense that adding it to a random stylesheet